# How to uv unwrap and bake image texture (image as plane - alpha) properly?

Tags: uv, texture-baking

[image]I tried following this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PslkSUNF6s
after that i tried to uv unwrap and baked once i set the "image to texture" to alpha clip.
somehow, the result comes with black color surrounding the leaf which im not desired?
(as in photo)

is there any proper way to bake alpha texture?

blender version: 2.80.75

Comment: I'd be very suprised if you could get a path tracer to bake transparency. This is not how they work. You can bake "your own" alpha channel by setting the material of the leaves to emit white light and bake emission. Use the result as alpha. 
If you want the fade effect you show in the bake, bake to white diffuse instead.

Comment: I found that it's not possible to do it if i keep doing the same way as i did previously, however, is there any workaround to do to get the leaf texture baked as i wanted to make it as an asset model. If what you said is possible, Is there any detail where i can use/watch to learn and replicate it on my own? What does the term called? White emission?

Comment: white emission: Emission shader, color white, strength 1. To test if you're on the right track, use your bake, then switch to bake emission, bake to another image. Then either in Blender, Gimp, whatever you prefer, use the colors of the emission bake for the alpha channel of the main image. That should do.